# Why == returns true?

Tags: java, conditional-statements

Why this condition returns true, as we know == returns true if both of the variable has same reference, but here the reference is not same but still it is entering in the loop and prints Hello World.

```
String var1="hi";
String var2="hi";

if(var1==var2){
    System.out.println("Hello World");
}
```

Comment: This code should not even compile.

Comment: oh.. sorry, it was my mistake, now edited.. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because Java has a pool of unique [interned](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) instances, and that String literals are stored in this pool. This means that the first "hi" string literal is exactly the same String object as the second "hi" literal.

Answer (score 4):

When you assign to string literals to variables, you are likely to get the reference to the same object, as Strings are cached and immutable, so those string actually have the same reference.

Comment: On the other hand, if you declared `var2 = new String("hi")`, the check would return `false` as you expect.

Comment: You are * guaranteed* to get the same reference for string literals as long as they fulfill the equality contract. And not all Strings are cached, only literals and explicitly `interned` ones are.

Comment: @Perception And not just String literals, but any String the compiler identifies as a constant. `"one2" == "one" + 2`, for instance.  (See: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.5 ) @ParthSoni, what are you trying to check for -- identity equality, or "logical" equality? You can use `String.equals` or `String.equalsIgnoringCase` for the latter.

Comment: @yshavit - good point, as long as all the strings involved are literals.

Answer (score 2):

When you assign a String literal to a String, that literal is stored as a String instance into memory. Further assignments of the same literal will point to the same memory location. So if `var1` and `var2` were declared of type String, then `var1 == var2` will return `true`, because they point to the same String instance `"hi"`.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared var1 and var2 as int instead of String.

My compiler refuses to compile the code, saying "incompatible types".

Your compiler probably casts the string "hi" into some number, for example 0, because the variables should have number values.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [jvm specifcation](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/lexical.doc.html).

**String literals-or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions (§15.28)-are "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method String.intern.**

Answer (score 0):

It comes true because of this
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.5
Most of the answers here already pointed you into the right direction, but it's better to read the source of truth.